# Do I need to enroll in "Apple Developer Program Enrollment" for creating a certificate?

Tags: development, developer-program, certificate

I have a website that I am trying to convert to a iOS app using Phonegap. But it requires that I provide ‘certificate (p12) file’ and a ‘provisioning profile’. I  am using a Windows machine and have been following [this tutorial](https://www.iandevlin.com/blog/2012/11/phonegap/building-an-ios-signing-key-for-phonegap-in-windows). So far I have managed to complete till the second step and created `ios.csr` file.

The nest step in the tutorial says

> Click on “Certificates” in the left hand side, and then “Request”. You will be prompted to upload a .csr file, and then wait for the certificate to be issued.

But I am unable to find any such button, do I require to enroll in for "Apple Developer Program" to get the certificate?

Is there any alternative way? As the website itself is a prototype and since we are currently in the research and development phase, I cannot invest any money in this program now.

Answer (score 1):

There is a long rambling discussion [here](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2189824) on this topic but the crux is: yes, to get a Development Certificate without a Mac you need a full developer account.

An alternative is to get your hands on a Mac, from where you can do everything for free up until the point where you need to distribute your app to the App Store.